# Is CUDA shared memory also cached

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu-cache, gpu-shared-memory

In my CUDA application, I am copying data from device memory to shared memory. Is that data cached in L1 as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all memory loads from global memory are cached in L1. The target location for the global memory load has no effect on the L1 caching (whether it is a register, or shared memory or thread local memory). The shared memory itself is obviously not cached.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to expand on what @talonmies said.

A copy is two separate operations at a low level, a load and a store. Both load and store can be cached in L1 and L2 if they access global memory.

Since the load part of your copy is from global memory, it will be cached both in L1 and L2 by default. So, unless the compiler detects the special situation of copying from global to shared memory and uses an uncached load, you end up with two copies of your data that can be accessed at the same latency because the shared memory and L1 cache are implemented with the same physical on-chip memory.

From the CUDA C Programming Guide 4.2:

> There is an L1 cache for each multiprocessor and an L2 cache shared by all
> multiprocessors, both of which are used to cache accesses to local or global
> memory, including temporary register spills. The cache behavior (e.g. whether reads
> are cached in both L1 and L2 or in L2 only) can be partially configured on a per-access basis using modifiers to the load or store instruction.

I couldn't find anything about how this behavior may be modified from CUDA C.

### Update:

Since CUDA 11 there are [Load Functions Using Cache Hints](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#load-functions-using-cache-hints) (store as well). So one could use e.g. `__ldcg()` to avoid caching in L1. Previously these cache hints were already available through inline PTX assembly.

Note however that if there is overlap between the global memory locations accessed by different blocks residing on the same SM, L1 caching might still be beneficial. The overlap might even be incidental due to L1 cache line granularity.

Comment: It can't be modified in user code, but for Fermi and Kepler devices, it can be modified by compiler options. Using `-Xptxas="-dlcm=cg"` will force the assembler to generate 32 byte rather than 128 byte transactions which bypass the L1 cache.